# Lineage 2 (game) cant run

Tags: games

I have download and install lineage 2(game) and i search on internet how to run it the only  think i found was to download wine and then i will be able to play it.but i downloaded  and  when i  double click on the l2.exe i can see it on the system monitor running for 1 min but then dissapear , and the game is not running at all.  i dunno know what else to do  can you help me? I have download and install lineage 2(game) and i search on internet how to run it the only think i found was to download wine and then i will be able to play it.but i downloaded and when i double click on the l2.exe i can see it on the system monitor running for 1 min but then dissapear , and the game is not running at all. i dunno know what else to do can you help me?

Comment: sr i put the question 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a `.exe` or any other executable file, that has been **compiled and linked for Windows**, under Ubuntu or any other operating system other than Windows.

So you do basically have three solutions:

1. Get the **sources** of the game and build it for your processor architecture and system (ubuntu)
2. Get a **pre-built** executable file for your processor architecture and operating System
3. install **`wine`** and run it in an emulated Windows.

I guess that *Lineage 2* is *not open-source and does probably not support Linux*, so options 1 and 2 would not lead to anything.

To **use option 3** you need to install `wine` first:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

and once `wine` is installed, run the executable with `wine`:

```
wine l2.exe
```

Comment: THEolodis hey mate i cant do wune l2.exe i get an error cause i have not install the game in C:/ i install it on my documents cause when i install it in c:/ i couldent find the folder

Answer (score 0):

From the Wine HQ App page (https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2273): the latest version of Lineage 2 (Goddess of Destruction) does not work in Wine yet.

If you have an interest in MMOs, I would suggest to select one that has a native Linux client. Some of the MMOs that have Linux clients:

- Wakfu (http://www.wakfu.com/en/mmorpg | http://www.wakfu.com/en/mmorpg/what-is-wakfu?from=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wakfu.com%2Fen%2Fmmorpg)
- Zezenia Online (http://www.zezeniaonline.com/)
- Other-Life (http://www.other-life.com/)
- Stendhal (https://stendhalgame.org/)
- Champions of Regnum (http://www.championsofregnum.com/)
- Ryzom (http://ryzom.com/)
- Heroes of Umbra (http://heroesofumbra.com/)